# Points of psline are in reverse order in Postscript code

Tags: pstricks, animate, dvips, postscript

I build an animation (using animateinline of animate-package in a beamer presentation) containing a \psline with 4 points. The points are calculated with "postscript math". I wanted to include the calculation only once, so I use several postscript *def* commands to reuse the results of the postsript calculations in all of the other points. I found the 4 points in the postscript file, but in reverse order, so I have to put the calculations and the *def*-commands into the last of the 4 points. All works fine, but my questions are:

1.) can I rely on this reverse order for future updates or

2.) is there an more elegant way to include the postscript calculation and def-commands used in the 4 points of \psline?

3.) is it possible to print the calculated values (e.g. "UL" in the minimum code example) in the pspicture?

In the minimal code example "UL", "UR" and "xposi" are the reused values, "anzl" and "anzr" are temporary definitions for the calculation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[svgnames,pdf]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{animate}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\newcommand\dceininz[4]{
\begin{pspicture}(-0.7,-1.2)(5.8,1.7)%
\psaxes[ticks=y,labels=y,labelsep=2pt,dy=1,Dy=#2]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-1.0)(5.5,1.6)[$z$,0][$u/V$,270]
\FPset\time{#1}
\FPdiv\time\time{5.0}
\FPclip\time\time
\rput[b](2.5,-0.9){$t=\time\tau$}
\psline[linecolor=black!40](! 0 #4\space 1 add #3\space 1 sub mul #3\space #4\space mul 1 sub div 1 #3\space sub div)%
                           (! 5 #4\space 1 add #3\space 1 sub mul #3\space #4\space mul 1 sub div 1 #3\space sub div)
% THIS IS THE PSLINE WITH 4 POINTS
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=blue](! 0 UL)(! xposi UL)(! xposi UR)%%
    (! /anzl #1\space 10 div floor 2 mul def /anzr #1\space 5 add 10 div floor 2 mul 1 sub def %
       /UL 0 def 0 1 anzl {dup #3\space exch 2 idiv exp exch #4\space exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul /UL exch UL add def} for %
       /UR 0 def 0 1 anzr {dup #3\space exch 2 idiv exp exch #4\space exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul /UR exch UR add def} for #1\space 5 div floor cvi 0 eq {/UR 0 def} {} ifelse %
       /xposi #1\space #1\space 5 div floor 5 mul sub #1\space cvi 10 mod 5 lt {} {5 exch sub} ifelse def 5 UR)
\psline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
\rput[t](5,-0.15){$z$}
\end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Minimum Example: transmission line with dc excitation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{128mm}
\begin{center}
\psset{xunit=0.8}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=0,controls={play,step,stop}]{10}%
\multiframe{101}{ntmpi=0.00+0.5}{\dceininz{\ntmpi}{8}{-0.6}{0.6}}%
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I am using "latex.exe" -> "dvips.exe -T 363pt,273pt" -> Acrobat ps2pdf

Thanks in advance, Fritz

Comment: Your workflow should be changed. First create a multipage PDF file consisting of the frames to be animated. Second, use `animategraphics` in your main TeX file to include the PDF.

Comment: Thanks, but I think this would not help me: I like to have all of the source code in my tex-file (and the code works). Changing the workflow, I would have the same effect when creating the multipage PDF file, because I would generate this with my usual workflow.

Comment: Could you show me the function you want to plot in terms of `t` and `z`? I think you can find the closed form so you don't need to use `for` here.

Comment: Sorry, I dont have a closed formula. You have to evaluate first how many reflections did happen. Its similar to pulses on transmission lines. Please see: https://www.industrial-electronics.com/measurement-testing-com/hsdsd_2.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.) can I rely on this reverse order for future updates or

PostScript calculation is always represented in Reverse Polish Notation regardless of the incoming updates.

The PostScript code in `\psline(A)(B)(C)(D)` is processed from `D`  to `A` looks weird to me too. Will it be changed in the future? Maybe not!

> 2.) is there an more elegant way to include the postscript calculation and def-commands used in the 4 points of \psline?

I have tried refactoring your original code. Put the common PostScript constants in `\pstVerb`. Don't forget to append a trailing percent sign to remove the unwanted white spaces.

> 3.) is it possible to print the calculated values (e.g. "UL" in the minimum code example) in the pspicture?

PostScript values cannot be printed. But if you want to print it, there is another trick. Define a TeX macro, for example `\def\UL{\psCalculate{}}`, then you can print it with `\rput(...,...){\UL}`.

My suggestion: Separate the contents from the code for generating graphics.

## First

Create a new TeX input file named `graph.tex` as follows.

```
% graph.tex
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate}
\sisetup
{
    round-integer-to-decimal,% optional
    round-mode=places,
    round-precision=1
}

\newcommand\atom[4]{
\begin{pspicture}(-0.7,-1.2)(5.8,1.7)%
\psaxes[ticks=y,labels=y,labelsep=2pt,dy=1,Dy=#2]{->}%
            (0,0)(-0.5,-1.1)(5.5,1.6)[$z$,0][$u/V$,180]
\pstVerb
{%
    /one #1 def /two #2 def /three #3 def /four #4 def
    /anzl one 10 div floor 2 mul def 
    /anzr one 5 add 10 div floor 2 mul 1 sub def 
    /tmp four 1 add 1 three four mul sub div def
}%
\psline[linecolor=black!40](!0 tmp)(!5 tmp)

% THIS IS THE PSLINE WITH 4 POINTS
\psline[linewidth=1pt,linecolor=blue]
  (!0 UL)(!xposi UL)(!xposi UR)%
  (! /UL 0 def 
            0 1 anzl 
            {dup    three exch 2 idiv exp exch four exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul 
                        /UL exch UL add def
            } for
      /UR 0 def 
            0 1 anzr 
            {dup    three exch 2 idiv exp exch four exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul 
                        /UR exch UR add def
            } for 
            one 5 div floor cvi 0 eq {/UR 0 def} {} ifelse 
      /xposi    one dup 5 div floor 5 mul sub 
                            one cvi 10 mod 5 lt {} {5 exch sub} ifelse 
            def 
            5 UR
  )
\psline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
\rput[b](2.5,-0.9){$t=\psCalculate{#1/5}\tau$}
\rput[t](5,-0.15){$z$}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\n=0.00+0.50}{101}{\atom{\n}{8}{-0.6}{0.6}}
\end{document}
```

Compile it with `latex-dvips-ps2pdf` building flow. Now you have a multipage PDF named `graph.pdf`. Each page represent a frame of your animation.

[image]

## Second

From within your main TeX input file (that is the file to generate your presentation with `beamer`) import the `graph.pdf` with `animategraphics` as follows. Compile it **TWICE** with `pdflatex` to make the animation works!

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{animate}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Minimum Example: transmission line with dc excitation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{128mm}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,loop,autoplay,scale=1.5]{5}{graph}{}{}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The explanation about `animategraphics`:

```
\animategraphics[palindrome,controls,loop,autoplay,scale=<scale>]{<frame rate>}{"<diagram filename>"}{}{}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will implement a combination of your suggestion and the one of the second answer of user187802

Answer (score 1):

Define the points as an own macro:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[svgnames]{pstricks}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{animate}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{dolphin}

\def\getCoor#1#2#3#4{
  /anzl #1\space 10 div floor 2 mul def /anzr #1\space 5 add 10 div floor 2 mul 1 sub def 
  /UL 0 def 0 1 anzl {dup #3\space exch 2 idiv exp exch #4\space exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul /UL 
  exch UL add def} for 
  /UR 0 def 0 1 anzr {dup #3\space exch 2 idiv exp exch #4\space exch 1 add 2 idiv exp mul 
  /UR exch UR add def} for #1\space 5 div floor cvi 0 eq {/UR 0 def} {} ifelse 
  /xposi #1\space #1\space 5 div floor 5 mul sub #1\space cvi 10 mod 5 lt {} {5 exch sub} 
   ifelse def 5 UR }

\newcommand\dceininz[4]{%
\begin{pspicture}(-0.7,-1.2)(5.8,1.7)
\psaxes[ticks=y,labels=y,labelsep=2pt,dy=1,Dy=#2]{->}(0,0)(-0.5,-1.0)(5.5,1.6)[$z$,0][$u/V$,270]
\FPset\time{#1}
\FPdiv\time\time{5.0}
\FPclip\time\time
\rput[b](2.5,-0.9){$t=\time\tau$}
\psline[linecolor=black!40]%
  (! 0 #4\space 1 add #3\space 1 sub mul #3\space #4\space mul 1 sub div 1 #3\space sub div)%
  (! 5 #4\space 1 add #3\space 1 sub mul #3\space #4\space mul 1 sub div 1 #3\space sub div)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=blue](! 0 UL)(! xposi UL)(! xposi UR)(! \getCoor{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4})
\psline(5,-0.1)(5,0.1)
\rput[t](5,-0.15){$z$}
\end{pspicture}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Minimum Example: transmission line with dc excitation}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{128mm}
\begin{center}
\psset{xunit=0.8}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=0,controls={play,step,stop}]{10}%
\multiframe{101}{ntmpi=0.00+0.5}{\dceininz{\ntmpi}{8}{-0.6}{0.6}}%
\end{animateinline}
\end{center}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you ask me? It is not my code ...

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer Should be sad or haha ? :-)

Comment: Report: The fourth argument of  `\pstMarkAngle[Options]{A}{B}{C}` is missing on page 11 of `pst-eucl` documentation. It must be corrected to `\pstMarkAngle[Options]{A}{B}{C}{Label}`.

Comment: @user187802: Thank your for your answer. It's a good idea to define the points as an own macro. Even if the order of points in postcript is changed, it will be easy to implement this.